# How to exclude UIActivityTypeAirDrop when developing with iOS SDK 6 on XCode?

Tags: uiactivity, uiactivitytypeairdrop

I want to exclude the UIActivityTypeAirDrop from my UIActivitySheet. Unfortunately this const is only available from SDK 7 on but I have to build for SKD 6. Defining the const by myself does not work (as expected). Is there a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can:
1) Build from SDK 7 and disable/exclude it
2) Do nothing about it

There really is no reason why you shouldn't build from SDK 7.